# Knockout: Bind uploaded files

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have ran into an issue of being unable to upload multiple files from nested models within the main knockout view model.

Testing out uploading HttpPostedFileBase properties, I was succesful in uploading a file and using two synchronous ajax calls within the EditTestStepjs file, using the XmlFile property.

However, in trying to send over multiple files that are bound to the nested models within the list, I am unable to have their values sent over to the controller using form-data.

Nested View Model

```
public class XmlParameterViewModel
{
    public string ParameterName { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase XmlValue { get; set; }
}
```

Main View Model

```
public class EditTestStepViewModel
{
    public string TestStepName { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase XmlFile { get; set; }
    public List<XmlParameterViewModel> XmlParameters { get; set; }

    public EditTestStepViewModel()
    {
        this.XmlParameters = new List<XmlParameterViewModel>();
    }

}
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveEdit(EditTestStepViewModel editTestStepViewModel)
    {
        return View("Index", editTestStepViewModel);
    }

    public JsonResult FileUpload(List<HttpPostedFileBase> xmlFile)
    {
        return Json(new {success = true}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

EditTestStepJS file

```
var EditTestStepViewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;

    ko.validatedObservable(ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, self));

    self.saveTestStep = function() {
        if (self.isValid()) {

            var file = new FormData($("#editForm").get(0));

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/FileUpload/",
                data: file,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () {

                    var dataToSend = ko.mapping.toJSON(self);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Home/SaveEdit/",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        data: dataToSend
       });
     }
   });
 }
}
```

View

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="editForm">

 <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>XmlPara</th>
        </tr>

        <tbody data-bind="foreach: XmlParameters">
        <tr>
            <td class="form-group"> <input name="ParameterName" class="form-control input-sm" data-bind="value: ParameterName"  disabled="disabled"/></td>
            <td class="form-group"> <input name="XmlValue" type="file" class="btn btn-group" data-bind="value: XmlValue" /></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
        <button data-bind="click: saveTestStep" type="submit">Save Test Step</button>

<form>
```

Comment: Can you post the actual request by the browser?

Comment: I suspect that your html input name does not mapped properly into your property `public List<XmlParameterViewModel> XmlParameters { get; set; }`.